# Catch Access DB Error (FormatException) And Return Custom Message?

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access, error-handling, try-catch

I have an access database with a field that requires an integer. I am passing in some data that is retrieved from an Excel spreadsheet and if a string is retrieved from the cell then the calling function's Try/Catch will hit a FormatException. What I am trying to figure out is if it's possible (and it always is) to throw a custom error message that will display the cell address that contained the invalid data. Here is some example code of what I have.

```
Public Class Main
Private cellAddress As String
Private Sub btn_Import(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    Dim openFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True
    If openFileDialog.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        ImportWorksheet(New FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName))
    Catch ex As FormatException
        MessageBox.Show("The data contained within cell " & cellAddress &  " is invalid.", "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ImportWorksheet(ByVal excelFile As FileInfo)
    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.cnn)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = GetCommand("UpdateSite")
    Dim worksheet1 As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    Using package As New ExcelPackage(excelFile)
        Using cmd.Connection
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyData", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GetCellContents(worksheet1, "K8")
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
End Sub

Private Function GetCellContents(ByVal worksheet As ExcelWorksheet, ByVal address As String) As Object
    If worksheet.Cells(address).Value Is Nothing Then
        Return DBNull.Value
    Else
        cellAddress = address
        Return worksheet.Cells(address).Value
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Don't think I'm missing anything here, I kind of copied and pasted and altered the code to shorten and not give up any unneeded info. Once the code hits the ExecuteNonQuery() method, the error bubbles up and says whatever I have written in. I want to pass the cell address when this happens if at all possible so they know where to look.

The only way I can think of doing this would be to add a class level variable and set it to the current cell every time it gets the value. The only issue is that since it only fires at ExecuteNonQuery(), and I have multiple parameters, if the first added parameter is invalid but the next parameter isn't, then the cell is set to the last parameter every time and I get the wrong result. Is there a way to get some kind of message back from the database that will tell me specifically which parameter didn't convert properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just went with this for now... It works, but if you guys can give me something better, please do.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyData", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GetCellContents(worksheet2, "K8", "Int32")

 Private Function GetCellContents(ByVal worksheet As ExcelWorksheet, ByVal address As String, Optional ByVal type As String = Nothing) As Object
    If worksheet.Cells(address).Value Is Nothing Then
        Return DBNull.Value
    Else
        cellAddress = address
        Select Case type
            Case Is = "String"
                Return Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells(address).Value)
            Case Is = "Int32"
                Return Convert.ToInt32(worksheet.Cells(address).Value)
            Case Is = "DateTime"
                Return Convert.ToDateTime(worksheet.Cells(address).Value)
            Case Else
                Return worksheet.Cells(address).Value
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```